# How to calculate $\log_5\tan(36^\circ)+\log_5\tan(54^\circ)$ without a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

$$\log_5\tan(36^\circ)+\log_5\tan(54^\circ)=\log_5(\tan(36^\circ)\tan(54^\circ)).$$ I cannot solve those 2 tangent functions above. Here calculator comes in handy to calculate it. Is there a method of evaluating this problem without a calculator?

Comment: HInt: $36^\circ+54^\circ =?$

Comment: HInt: $36^\circ+54^\circ =90$ so 
$$tan(54^\circ)=cot(36^\circ)\\$$

Comment: $\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\cos x$ and $\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\sin x$ explain the identity used by Khosrotash in the previous hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HInt: $36^\circ+54^\circ =90$ so 
$$tan(54^\circ)=cot(36^\circ)\\$$
$$\log_5\tan(36^\circ)+\log_5\tan(54^\circ)=\log_5(\tan(36^\circ)\tan(54^\circ))=\\\log_5(\tan(36^\circ)\cot(36^\circ))=log_5(1)=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\tan(36^\circ)=\tan(90^\circ-54^\circ)=\frac{1}{\tan54^\circ}$

$$\log_5(\tan(36^\circ)\tan(54^\circ))$$

$$=\log_5(\frac{1}{\tan54^\circ}\tan(54^\circ))$$

$$=\log_5(1)=0$$